# how to get same foreign_key record from multiple row in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, group-by

I am trying to get record having same ID in array. I tried the "Group_by" query but  the result in single array. See the record in the following image.

[image]

**Query:**

```
$this->db->select('typeID,projectID,typeName,typeSize,dimensionWidth,dimensionHeight');
$this->db->from('propertytype');
$this->db->group_by('projectID');
$rec=$this->db->get()->result();

echo "<pre>";print_r($rec);exit();
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
   [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [typeID] => 1
        [projectID] => 1
        [typeName] => Residential
        [typeSize] => 5 MARLA
        [dimensionWidth] => 125
        [dimensionHeight] => 125
    )

   [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [typeID] => 7
        [projectID] => 2
        [typeName] => Residential
        [typeSize] => 5 MARLA
        [dimensionWidth] => 26
        [dimensionHeight] => 50
    )

)
```

I want the result in 2 dimensional array like.

```
Array(
  [0]=> stdClass object(
      Array(...)
      Array(...)
      Array(...)
      Array(...)
  )

  [1]=> stdClass object(
      Array(...)
      Array(...)
      Array(...)
      Array(...)
  )
)
```

Tell me where am i making a mistake? Can any one help me please. I will be very thankful.

Comment: the GROUP BY clause is often used with Aggregate Functions to return summary values for each group. The GROUP BY clause without aggregates is similar to using SELECT DISTINCT. ... The GROUP BY clause does not order data.

Comment: you can use `order_by('projectID')` instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` clause is often used with `Aggregate Functions` to return summary values for each group. The `GROUP BY` clause without aggregates is similar to using `SELECT DISTINCT`. ... The `GROUP BY` clause does not order data.

I hope this help you:

```
$this->db->select('projectID');
$this->db->from('propertytype');
$this->db->distinct('projectID');
$rec=$this->db->get()->result();
$arr=array();

foreach ($rec as $r) {
    $this->db->select('typeID,projectID,typeName,typeSize,dimensionWidth,dimensionHeight');
    $this->db->from('propertytype');
    $this->db->where('projectID',$r->projectID);
    $rec=$this->db->get()->result();
    $arr[]=$rec;    
}

echo "<pre>";print_r($arr);exit();
```

Comment: wlc dear Jamal Ahmad